# Function to export to file is changing the lists

Tags: python

I have this snippet of code to export 5 lists to one file.

The problem is after this code is run, the layout of the lists is all changed.  Is there something in the code that is changing the lists, and can I adjust for that?

Thank you,

Here is the code I am using:

```
def employee_export():
    global employeeName, employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary
    employeeList = zip(employeeName, employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary)

    with open('employees.txt','w') as employees:
        for (employeeName, employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary) in employeeList:
            employees.write('{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}\n'.format(employeeName, employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary))
```

Comment: The `for` loop is an assignment statement. Don't use your global variables as target names.

Comment: Better, don't use globals. Pass these values into the functions they need to be used in.

Answer (score 2):

`for` loops are assignment statements, and you are overwriting the global names with elements from the original lists. Pick different target names.

```
def employee_export():
    employeeList = zip(employeeName, employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary)

    with open('employees.txt','w') as employees:
        for (f1, f1, f3, f4, f5) in employeeList:
            employees.write('{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}\n'.format(f1, f2, f3, f4, f5))
```

Better yet, don't bother unpacking a tuple that you can pass directly to `' '.join`:

```
def employee_export():
    employeeList = zip(employeeName, employeeSSN, employeePhone, employeeEmail, employeeSalary)

    with open('employees.txt','w') as employees:
        for t in employeeList:
            employees.write(' '.join(t))
```

Comment: This is beautiful, thank you.  I knew I was doing some writing to the files because I had to add global declarations for all the lists.